# Report reviewers - temporary retract review permissions?

Tags: feature-request, moderation

I'd like to have the ability to report users that doing bad reviews again and again.

If the user gets reported X times in a given period, he/she should not be able to do further reviews for X days/weeks.

Reason:

There are several topics about bad reviews and you'll always see the same guys mentioned.

Even unintended code changes or removed code formating are blindly accepted. The first approval was within one minute after the edit was made ... no time to read, just hit "OK"?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/162966

If it's not possible, mods should consider to give them a break (setpoints to 1).

Sorry, but I don't want to see my posts edited in this way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the ability to report users that do bad reviews / edits.
Just flag one of the user's posts (Or the edited port) explaining what the problem is.
No, there is no automated system that does this: "X reports means Y period banned from reviewing / suggesting edits.".
Yes, moderators can temporarily (manually) suspend users from reviewing / suggesting edits.